# postGIS very slow st_buffer query - How to improve performance

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, postgis, spatial

I'm using postGIS within a postgreSQL spatial database. I want to create homerange polygons from buffers around movement paths for each of 48 animals(GPS locations connected with a line). I have location data of 264'000 data points of 48 different animals.
I do this in 3 steps to improve performance. The problem is the second step (st_buffer to create buffers around paths). If I run step 2 below for a single animal (6000 locations) it takes roughly 3 minutes. If I run the second step for a subset (one third) of the data for all animals it takes 30 minutes.
Now that I'm running the query for all data it's been running for more than 5 hours and I'm not sure this will return successfully at all. Is there any reason why the running time would not grow more or less in a linear fashion?  Can anyone tell me if there is something wrong with my code or if one could improve on the performance of my code. Any suggestion would be most appreciated!!

Step 1: First create a temporary table with the movement paths - Use st_simplify to simplify the paths with a float parameter of 10m

```
create table ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_all_step1 as
select gps.animals_original_id, st_simplify(st_makeline(gps.geom_21781),10) as geom
from (select animals_original_id,acquisition_time, geom_21781
from ws_zurich.mirco
order by animals_original_id, acquisition_time) as gps
group by gps.animals_original_id;

Alter table ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_all_step1
ADD CONSTRAINT polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_step1_pkey PRIMARY KEY(animals_original_id);
```

Step 2: Create a table with the buffer around the movement paths - this is the slowest query and takes several hours for the entire data set

```
create table ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_all_step2 as
select animals_original_id, (st_buffer(geom, 104)) as geom
from ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_all_step1;
```

-- Step 3: use st_union to create a single polygon as home range

```
create table ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_post_hunting as
select row_number() over (order by animals_original_id) as id,animals_original_id,(st_union(geom)) as geom
from ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_post_hunting_step2 group by animals_original_id;

Alter table ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_post_hunting
ADD CONSTRAINT polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_post_hunting_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: Could you show us the results of EXPLAIN and/or EXPLAIN ANALYZE ?

Comment: Have you tuned your PostgreSQL installation for better performance? If not, [see this guideline](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/tuning.html)

Comment: @Mike T - Thanks for the link, the db is on a external server that should be tuned correctly as far as I know

Comment: @FrankHeikens - Here is the EXPLAIN of step 2 - "Seq Scan on polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_all_step1 (cost=0.00..13.48 rows=48 width=64)" - I've never used EXPLAIN and don't know how to interpret the output.

Comment: Are you sure? A table with only 48 rows is almost empty, that could never take 5 hours to read. Unless the table is locked and you're waiting for this other proces to unlock the table... It could also that the statistics aren't up to date and you have to run ANALYZE;

Comment: @FrankHeikens - Yes it is really only 48 rows (one per animal). The slow part apparently is to draw a buffer around a very complicated line. In step 1 I use st_makeline to connect all locations per animal (each animal ~6000 locations) and then draw the buffer of 104m around this line (this line is the path the animal moved). But 5hours seems still very slow even if the line is long and complicated. And I will have to do this many times, so I need a better way. PS: The query was succesfull in the end after 6.2 hours

Comment: Could you show us the EXPLAIN for all SELECT-statements? Especially the slowest one.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - Explain for the slow query (step 2) ' select animals_original_id, (st_buffer(geom, 104)) as geom
from ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_all_step1 ' is "Seq Scan on polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_all_step1  (cost=0.00..13.48 rows=48 width=64)". Step 1 and Step 3 only take a few seconds. Is this what you are interested to see? I'm sorry I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Are you sure it takes 5 hours to read 48 records? At the start of your topic you mention "select animals_original_id, (st_buffer(geom, 104)) as geom
from ws_zurich.polygon_homerange_104m_mirco_all_step1;" as being the slowest part

Comment: @FrankHeikens - Yes I'm sure - it has to calculate 48 geometries from buffers around the line strings created in step 1. Keep in mind that one linestring from st_makeline is very long and looks like a ball of wool. I could provide you with the shapefile of the step 1 so you could replicate if that helps